# How to unwrap nested divs?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Im trying to unwrap empty divs and get inner elements from this nested div using HTML Agility Pack

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
        <div>
          <span>Test 1</span>
          <p>Test 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired Output:

```html
<div>
  <span>Test 1</span>
  <p>Test 2</span>
</div>
```

Here's what i tried so far, just identifying the next and previous siblings

```
var html = @"<body>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>Test</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        
        var nodes =  htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants();    
        
        foreach(var g in nodes)
        {
            if(g.PreviousSibling != null)
                Console.WriteLine(g.PreviousSibling.Name);
            else 
               Console.WriteLine("No Previous");

            Console.WriteLine(g.Name);
            
            if(g.NextSibling != null)
                Console.WriteLine(g.NextSibling.Name);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No Next");
            
        }
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the code in your question?

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).